# can i maintain 5 prices for a product with the same currency based on its volume?

Tags: pricebook, pricebookentry, standard

The current status of out business is such that , they maintain different prices for different cities in the same country.

Also, they maintain different prices for different volumes. Example : Different price for grams unit , and different prices for Kilograms( these are mere 2 units, there are other Sales Unit of measure as well )

How do I achieve this functionality ?

Is there anyway of having multiple standard prices for a product in same currency

Comment: Each Price Book Entry is limited to one per product per price book per currency. Typically, users would modify a volume price by applying a line item discount. Other solutions include creating multiple product records (e.g. one for each level of discount), or creating a customization/code that automatically applies the correct price based on volume. I believe there's probably some apps out there on the AppExchange that can also do this, but I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 3):

A single product cannot have multiple prices in a pricebook.

So, there are 2 options:

1. Create duplicate products with unique product codes and define prices. You can create unit of measurement as custom field for which you are defining the price. That can be added in a Single Pricebook.
2. Create different pricebooks for each units and add product into that and define the price.

Comment: `A single product cannot have multiple prices in a pricebook` sb `A single product cannot have multiple prices for the same currency in a pricebook`

Comment: Yes, thats why duplicate the products

Comment: your solution was fine; the wording of the first sentence was ambiguous - a product can have multiple prices in a pricebook, for example SKU FOO could be 120 USD and 110 EUR; two prices in same pricebook. But, as your solution indicates, you can't have for SKU FOO in Pricnebook P a pricebookentry for 120 USD and 100 USD.